# JQuery document.getElementById("graficoXXX") - id variable

Tags: html, jquery, chart.js

¿como puedo llamar hacer la llamada a un id de un nodo de nombre variable?
En el codigo html se genera el nombre según el contenido de un campo de la base de datos ..

```
echo "<div align='center'><canvas id='grafico".$nom['cod']."' name='grafico".$nom['cod']."' width='280vw' height='240vw'></canvas></div>";
```

En este caso, el id puede ser 'grafico001', 'grafico002', .. 'grafico025', ... etc

Para dibujar el grafico con Chart.js busco el id desde jquery

```
var ctx_gp = document.getElementById("graficoXXX");
```

donde XXX puede ser 001, 002, .. 025, ... ¿como es la sintaxis para que esto funcione?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tal cual dice Bryro, pero en tu caso, como es un canvas, debes modificarlo asi:

```js
// selecccionamos todos los elementos que comienzen con la palabra graficos
graficos = document.querySelectorAll('canvas[id^=grafico]');

// recorremos e imprimimos
for(let x of graficos){
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="grafico001"></canvas>
<canvas id="grafico003"></canvas>
<canvas id="grafico004"></canvas>
<canvas id="grafico005"></canvas>
```

Ahora, si quieres traer cualquier elemento, sin importar que sea DIV o Canvas, solo debes modificar el código así:

```
var graficos = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=grafico]');
```

El selector `[id^=grafico]` es tal cual CSS, trae todos los IDs que empiecen con el texto `grafico`.

Comment: Genial. Muchas gracias :-)

Answer (score 1):

puedes hacerlo haciendo uso de los selectores avanzados en especifico el [selector de attributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)
ejemplo:

```js
// selecccionamos todos los elementos que comienzen con la palabra graficos
graficos = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^=grafico]');

// recorremos e imprimimos
for(let x of graficos){
  console.log(x);
}
```

```html
<div id="grafico001"></div>
<div id="nografico001"></div>
<div id="grafico002"></div>
<div id="nografico002"></div>
<div id="grafico003"></div>
<div id="nografico003"></div>
<div id="grafico004"></div>
<div id="nografico004"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como comenta el usuario Bryro, puedes hacer uso del selector de attributos. Además de eso, usarías *$(this)* para saber sobre que elemento es el que estamos ejecutando un evento.

En jQuery sería algo así:

```js
$(function() {
 $('div[id^="grafico"]').on('click', function() {
    let id_graphic = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(`Di click en ${id_graphic}`);
 });
});
```

```css
div{
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 background-color: coral;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grafico001">Gráfico 001</div>
<div id="grafico003">Gráfico 003</div>
<div id="grafico004">Gráfico 004</div>
<div id="grafico005">Gráfico 005</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es recoger todos a la vez en una colección de elementos puedes usar `document.querySelectorAll(".grafico")` siempre y cuando a todos les añadas `class="grafico"`. Si quieres coger uno en particular basta con concatenar el string al numero deseado `var ctx_gp = document.getElementById("grafico"+001);`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
var id = "grafico"+String(001); //Coloca el numero deseado

var ctx_gp = document.getElementById(id);
```